# how to disable scroll on sidenav

Tags: css

i want to ask

i have a show hide menu (openNav, closeNav)

this my javascript :

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "100%";
    // document.getElementById("flipkart-navbar").style.width = "50%";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
}
```

and this my css script :

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px -3px #555454;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

i try to add overflow-y: hidden; but not work

i try to change the overflow:visible or auto not work to

i try to change the position to absolute or relative not work to sir

the scroll still show

this my screenshoot :

[image]

see the scroll bar from my screenshoot, the scroll bar show not hide or disable

how to hide or disable the scrollbar sir?

thanks before

Comment: Try to replace height:100%; with bottom:0; in the CSS rule

Comment: thanks sir for reply @K K but not works sir i try to add bottom:0; not work, the scroll bar still show

Comment: Can you add complete markup and css for side nav? We can see you nav link item so add them as well.

Answer (score 1):

you need to target the overflow body element in js. Below is the code:

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "100%";
    // document.getElementById("flipkart-navbar").style.width = "50%";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
    document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
overflow: hidden;
height:100vh;
width: 100vh;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Having scrollbars is mostly the issue, that your sidebars content is too large, wide or high.

Try one of those:

1. Adding `overflow: hidden;` to .sidenav:
2. Adding `overflow: hidden;` to the parent element of sidenav
3. Add `right: 0;` and `bottom: 0;` to .sidenav

Comment: hi sir, thanks for reply
i try not work to sir :( the scroll bar still show

Answer (score 0):

Add these properties in your sidebar container or sidebar class.

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

or

```
Overflow:hidden;
```

Comment: thanks sir for reply, i try same to sir, the scroll still show, not work :(